# Neo4J - having repeating property or storing it implicitly

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling

I'm having this kind of model:

[image]

Where nodes have some unique properties (`p1`) and some repeating properties (`p2`). In my case, I could always say that if relation is `R1`, property `p2` will be unchanged (as in `OPTION2` - where nodes on the bottom have also `p2: B` but it is implicit).

Now I guess for programming and querying it would be easier to save always property on a node level, but since I will have million of this nodes, not-repeating properties could potentially save some space.

Question is - does Neo4j has some internal optimization for this and tree size will actually not get that big even when using repeating properties?

Comment: If those properties are repeating in such a high frequency that you are thinking on how to optimize it, you should probably consider them to be nodes instead of properties.

Comment: I also thought about this, but then I would have this "super node" problem that they talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your stated question: no, neo4j does not have any internal optimization to avoid storing the same property in multiple places in the DB if you tell it to do that.

Comment: OK. I guess in the end easiest thing here will be just to save p2: 0, p2: 1, ... p2: n -> where n is ordinal value of the enumerations, since this will be fixed and repeated on all nodes as a classifier.